# Whenever I open my terminal it shows that y: command not found. What is problem with it?

Tags: command-line

Every time I opened my terminal in Ubuntu 18.04, it shows that y: command not found, like this:

[image: Terminal]

What to do to solve this problem?

Comment: you likely have a shell init script in place that tries to run a command "y".  what shell are you running?  you should by running bash.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!   Can you please copy the contents of your .bashrc into the question?  It sounds like you may have added an incomplete command.

Comment: did you try to edit any files?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 8):

This could be caused by a line on the your `.bashrc` file that says `y`.

You could remove the offending line by editing the file by using:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Or if you have not modified the file yourself, you could restore the default `.bashrc`after taking a backup by running:

```
cp ~/.bashrc ~/bak.bashrc && cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

Comment: or it could have "y " and other stuff that won't matter

Answer (score 0):

I see this isn't a very recent thread, in my case it was caused by a wrong setting in  **/etc/environment**.  The file had been modified during the install of the Oracle DB client libraries (but it might be any other package)...

My problematic /etc/environment was this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/19.3/client64/lib:$PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/19.3/client64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Since we didn't need the Oracle client anymore, for us it was just a matter of deleting the last two lines, reverting it to the original content (after having uninstalled the Oracle client):

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```